# how to use .Contains LINQ in decimal fields

Tags: linq, asp.net-mvc-4, contains

I need to filter by a field of type decimal. How Do I?

Here's how I do for string fields:

```
cartaoCredito.strCartaoCreditoDescricao.ToUpper().Contains(strParam.ToUpper())
```

Here is my method:

```
public List<CartaoCredito> GetCartaoCreditoByintCodigoGrupoUsuarioByFiltro(int intCodigoGrupoUsuario, string strParam)
    {
        return (from cartaoCredito in _DatabaseContext.CartaoCredito
                where cartaoCredito.intCodigoGrupoUsuario == intCodigoGrupoUsuario && (cartaoCredito.strCartaoCreditoDescricao.ToUpper().Contains(strParam.ToUpper()))
                select cartaoCredito).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what you want to do here.

Comment: `Contains()` should work with numeric primitives as well.  In what way is it not working for you?

Comment: I'm confused - you want to filter to rows that have a value _within a given list_?

Comment: .Contains does not work, gives error.

Comment: @David - I think the original query uses `string.Contains`, not `IEnumerable<string>.Contains`.

Comment: To make it clear, I have a Grid that the user can filter by a particular column, just that I have columns with decimal values​​, but if I use. Contains giving errors

Comment: `decimal` does not have a `Contains` method - please provide the types for the _inputs_ and the _entities_.

Comment: @DStanley: Ah, I didn't notice that.  I'm not sure what's being asked then.  Numerics don't "contain" things in that sense...

Comment: @Danielle: Are you asking how to filter a numeric column when a user inputs a number that's lexicographically *part* of the displayed number?  Because in that case you're still talking about string comparison and you'd just need to convert the numbers to strings, then you can use `Contains` like you currently do.

Comment: I tried so and still does not work cartaoCredito.decCartaoCreditoLimite.ToString().Contains(strParam)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to translate a call to `string.Contains` to a decimal value, which won't work, because `decimal` does not have a `Contains` method like `string` does.

If you have a *collection* of `decimals` and you want to see if a value is within that list, do something like:

```
List<decimal> list = {list of decimals}

var query = {source}.Where(x => list.Contains(x.{decimal property});
```

or if you just have a single value, you do not need `Contains`.  Just do

```
decimal decParam = {some value};
var query = {source}.Where(x => x.{decimal property} = decParam);
```